# How to highlight dates in a specified range?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I have one column (`A`) of dates in Excel, each row representing one day of the year. I want to highlight a date if it's included in a list of dates (`$C$3:$C$28`) on the same page.

I want the date highlighted if it's a pay date that occurs every second Friday (every other Friday). I don't want to manually go through and select them piecemeal.

I've tried conditionally formatting the range by going to "Conditional Formatting" > "Highlight Cell Rules" > "Equal To" and specifying $C$3:$C$28. This obviously doesn't work.

Is there a conditional formatting formula I can plug in to highlight pay dates in my data range? Or, is there a macro that I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CF formula rule of:

```
=AND(WEEKDAY(A1)=6,MOD(COUNT(A$1:A1),2))
```

should work for every other Friday.

For the other Fridays from the above:

```
=AND(WEEKDAY(A1)=6,NOT(MOD(COUNT(A$1:A1),2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:
"Conditional Formatting" > "Highlight Cell Rules" > "Duplicate Cell Values"
and select all of Column A and $C$3:$C$28

It will highlight both columns A and C, but A will be highlighted.

Comment: How might I have solved this if I didn't have the list of pay dates? Namely, would there have been a way to calculate the date of every other Friday with conditional formatting or a Macro?

Comment: Try a "new rule" > "new formatting rule" > mod(A1+5,14) = 0
Format = highlight
You'll have to play around a little to make it work based on the right day (i.e. the +5), but that should make it work only based on the column.